# UISegmentedControl selected state icon image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

How can I set the icon image for `selected` state of the `UISegmentedControl`? Is the `UISegmentedControl` really missing this functionality or it is just me missing skills?

Comment: Follow this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281601/custom-uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: I think setting the target and then changing the image from target action will work for you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
   [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here I created two UISegmentedControl elements programmatically u can set image icon.

```
UISegmentedControl *switchView=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Yes",@"No",nil] autorelease]];
[switchView setFrame:CGRectMake(180,802,94,27)];
switchView.selectedSegmentIndex=1;
switchView.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[switchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchBlueBg.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];   // set icon for when selected
[switchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchOffPlain.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];  //set icon for when unselected
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(checkOnOffState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];             
[scrollview addSubview:switchView];

UISegmentedControl *switchView1=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Yes",@"No",nil] autorelease]];
[switchView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(180,1003,94,27)];
switchView1.selectedSegmentIndex=1;
switchView1.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[switchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchBlueBg.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];  // set icon for when selected
[switchView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchOffPlain.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];  ////set icon for when unselected
[switchView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(checkOnOffState1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[scrollview addSubview:switchView1];



-(IBAction)checkOnOffState:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl* tempSeg=(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    if(tempSeg.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        //your codes
    }
    else
    {
        //your codes
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:image 
                            forState:UIControlStateSelected
                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

You also have to set an image for `UIControlStateNormal` for this to take effect.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:)

Comment: Thanks for this: `You also have to set an image for UIControlStateNormal for this to take effect`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

This is how I managed it. Make a segmented control and insert segments using the images.

Be sure to set one image as selected as this will be the initial selected index. 
Also set the *backgroundColor* and *tintColor* to clear so that segmented control will only show your images.

```
var newSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()

        segmentedControl.insertSegment(with: UIImage(named: "x_Selected.jpg"), at: 0, animated: true)
        segmentedControl.insertSegment(with: UIImage(named: "y_Normal.jpg"), at: 1, animated: true)

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlChanged), for: .valueChanged)

        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .clear
        segmentedControl.tintColor = .clear            

    }()
```

Function called when the value of segmented control changes.

```
@objc func segmentedControlChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "x_Selected.jpg"), forSegmentAt: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "y_Normal.jpg"), forSegmentAt: 1)
    } else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "x_Normal.jpg"), forSegmentAt: 0)
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "y_Selected.jpg"), forSegmentAt: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    } 

}
```

Hope you find this useful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set by using single line of code **[uisegmentButtonRef setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"allbtndown.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:segmentIndex];**

If you use by Xib please find the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Enhancement of @Kuldeep's Answer**

you may have two or more controls in segmentcontrol

```
[_segmentcontrol addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

if you want to replace all images differently than use this code..

```
-(void)segmentAction:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calf_selected.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];//0 index
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wrist.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calf.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];//for 1 index
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wrist_selected.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```