# UISegmentedControl set selected image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I want my UISegmentedController to keep the same background color when selected, but just change the color of the image when selected. Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/3S0P1e3V2i432H0p1y12/Image%202014-11-16%20at%202.21.54%20PM.png

When the controller loads, segment 0 is selected and it's red. Upon clicking on segment 1, segment 0 turns white and segment 1 is red. Nothing else in the controller changes. I've read a bunch of posts on this but the best I can get is this [UISegmentedControl selected state icon image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480087/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-state-icon-image), however it doesn't seem to work for me.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: So uh...what's the problem ? When you tap on the heart or feet, it doesn't change to red colour ? It remains white colour ? You mean the background colour of the segment changes colour but the icon doesn't change colour ?

Comment: Yes precisely -- the icon doesn't change color. I'm looking to learn how to set the colors of images in the SegmentedController, both when they're selected and unselected.