# UISegmentedControl inside title of UINavigationBar looks unformatted

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to add a UISegmentedControl within the title of a UINavigationController. However, the formatting looks like this (i.e. its ugly).

[image]

When I want it to look like this (pretty :). Can anyone help??

[image]

I've read the popular example by Red Artisan [here](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited). But I'm not showing this as my first view (like Red Artisan does), so I've moved a lot of the code out of App Delegate. In App Delegate, I do set up this screen to be a UINavigationController with its rootView a UIViewController.

```
GenInfoViewController *genInfoController = [[GenInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GenInfoViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *genInfoNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:genInfoController];
```

Then in viewDidLoad of GenInfoViewController.m I do the following:

```
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Info",@"Map"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentedControl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style a segmented control, set the `segmentedControlStyle` property to one of the following:

```
UISegmentedControlStylePlain
UISegmentedControlStyleBordered
UISegmentedControlStyleBar
UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled
```

For example:

```
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Info",@"Map"]];
self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBordered;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentedControl;
```

There's some relevant Q+As on here regarding styling segment controls:

- [Custom segment control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281601/custom-uisegmentedcontrol)
- [Remove rounded corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834244/uisegmentedcontrol-without-rounded-corner)
- [Change font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280391/change-font-size-of-uisegmentedcontrol)
- [Change colour of selected segment](https://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/454)

**If you'd like to try a custom segmented control**, check out all the available [CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=segment&source=controls) and [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=segment&source=cocoapods).

Comment: `segmentedControlStyle` deprecated for iOS7+.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you need to set the property "segmentedControlStyle" on your UISegmented control.

Your options are as follows:

```
typedef enum {
   UISegmentedControlStylePlain,
   UISegmentedControlStyleBordered,
   UISegmentedControlStyleBar, // This is probably the one you want!
   UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled,
} UISegmentedControlStyle;
```

So the following should probably do the trick:

```
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Info",@"Map"]];
self.segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentedControl;
```

One thing you might also want to consider is setting the "tintColor" of the segmented control too.

```
self.segmentedControl = [UIColor blackColour];
```

Will leave you with something like this:

[image: UISegmented Control]

Obviously there is lots of other customisation you can do too. Take a look at the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html